# Multiple github accounts - Cloning through SSH but changing the HOST path still works?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have multiple github accounts, one for personal, and one for work.

In my .ssh/config

```
# personal account
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#work account
Host work.github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes  
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

I have a few questions:

1. for my work account, I couldn't have `Host github.com` because its already being used in my personal account, true? So to differentiate, I needed to do `Host work.github.com`? why?
2. how come I'm still able to SSH if I change a GitHub repo ssh url, by adding work.github.com

The original repo was

```
git@github.com:work-company-projects/work-repo.git
```

Cloning this would work, but I couldn't fetch. I was getting an error about needing access.

But once I cloned with this new SSH:

```
git@work.github.com:work-company-projects/work-repo.git
```

It worked. My `git remote -v` is following work.github.com host. I would have thought that I needed to keep the same host, @github.com, but changing this works too? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for my work account, I couldn't have Host github.com because its already being used in my personal account, true? So to differentiate, I needed to do Host work.github.com? why?

When connecting to Github via ssh everyone uses the same user, `git`. Users are identified by their ssh key. If you have multiple Github accounts, you need a different ssh key for each account.

Note that with [Github Organizations](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-organizations) there's no technical reason to have separate personal and work accounts.

> how come I'm still able to SSH if I change a GitHub repo ssh url, by adding work.github.com

You've configured SSH to use a different key depending on which host you *ask* to connect to, but ssh will still connect to github.com. This is a bit of a trick. SSH is customized per host, so you've made up a host `work.github.com`.

When you say to connect to `github.com` you've configured ssh to connect to `github.com` and use your key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

When you say to connect to `work.github.com` you've configured ssh to actually connect to `github.com`, that's what `HostName github.com` does, and use your work key `~/.ssh/id_rsa_work`.

So `git@work.github.com:work-company-projects/work-repo.git` is really connecting to github.com.

```
# tell ssh about work.github.com
Host work.github.com
    # When you ask to connect to work.github.com, connect to github.com instead.
    HostName github.com       
    # connect as the git user
    User git                  
    # add your key to the ssh-agent so yodon't have to keep retyping your password
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    # Get your ssh key password from your OS's keychain.
    UseKeychain yes
    # Use your work key
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```